# print lines if comma seperated fields matching together in another line

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

**Input:**

```
1,1,10,1
2,1,10,3
3,0,10,1
```

**Expected Output:**

```
1,1,10,1
2,1,10,3
```

So how to print lines if field number `2` and `3` repeated in another line.

Comment: Will those be adjacent lines, or scattered all over the place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick'n'dirty method (requiring two passes over the file, the first to count occurrences of `$2,$3`, and the second to print whenever the field combination is non-unique):

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$2 FS $3]++; next} a[$2 FS $3] > 1' file file
1,1,10,1
2,1,10,3
```

Comment: the only bad thing it's not showing the duplicate lines under together on big file. but it's did the job ! can i sort based on second and third field to appear under together?

Comment: I've done it by adding sort -t, -k2 . thanks a lot.